# Describing people who jump hoops to get a good deal

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is a precise and concise way of describing a person who goes out of their way to find deals or discounts for their purchases?

Suggestions which I'm not 100% happy with:

- Smart buyer
- Bargain hunter
- Deal chaser
- Discount hunter

Comment: "Bargain hunter" was my favourite. But, if you want to refer to negotiations on prices, you may define the person as a "haggler" (an hard bargainer). Example: *while haggling is the norm in the U.S. when buying a car or a home, most American prices on most items are non-negotiable*.

Comment: All of the definitions I can find define **_chiseler_** as a con man or swindler, but I've only ever heard it used to mean someone who tries to reduce the price of something beyond reason.

Comment: I like bargain hunter ... it doesn't convey  ... too far "over the top" jumping through hoops though... seems more like "one that is always looking for a good deal" .  A word like "monger"  Bargain-monger, deal monger.. would suggest a zestier appetite with a more obsessive flair... doesn't convey the  efforts though..

Comment: I've heard the term "Power shopper" before ... not sure if that is perfect though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"price-sensitive" is what I use

Answer (score 0):

This would also depend on the connotation you desire.  If you are trying to describe it as a positive quality, you could say:

- Thrifty
- Frugal
- Prudent
- Economical
- Sparing
- Provident

If you want to imply that the action is negative, you could describe them as being:

- Cheap
- Having a tight wallet
- Miserly
- Stingy
- Penny-pinching (or [your smallest native currency]-pinching)
- Parsimonious